# how to have different order confirmation emails for different scopes?

Tags: email, sales, scope

suppose we have two or three checkouts in different stores and we want to write customized confirmation emails for them I know that I can change the template for placing order in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html`
is it possible to create a folder of all other templates and have different confirmation emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new email template in

> System > Transactional emails

then assign this new template at store view level in

> System > Configuration > Sales Emails

and for example for

> "New Order Confirmation Template"

Answer (score 0):

What @TBI Infotech said will work, but if, like me, you don't like Magento's backend you can proceed as follow :

Say you want to have your email templates in French for your French store. You'll have to create a `app/locale/fr_FR/template/email/` folder, and then copy/paste your email templates from the `en_US` folder to this new location.

Once translated, you have to make sure that your French store is configured to use French language, you can change that in Magento's backend. Switch to the French store scope using the select in the top left, then go to
`System > Configuration > General > Localisation options > locale profile`
and select "French(France)" which will correspond to your `fr_FR` locale folder.

Everything should work as expected after that.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you,TBI answer is better although I got it before someone answer but it'll help people in the future, your answer is good too but I don't have french store I have many english stores so i cannot use this approach

Comment: Glad to help @NeginNickparsa